# Angular-beginner NgModel binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Beginner-level question:

I have a simple `input type=text` with `ng-model="xyz.zyx"`, where `xyz` is an object. In the controller, I create that object and assign a value to `zyx` property with the following assignment:

```
xyz {
  zyx: $scope.zzz
}
```

However, there are no input fields on the page with `ng-model="zzz"`, and yet, `zyx` is being assigned to the value of the input field that I described in the beginning, the one with `ng-model="xyz.zyx"` . 
How come this is happening? Where is `$scope.zzz` coming from?

Comment: `ng-model` sets up a 2 way data-binding. So if you type something into the input field it will set the variable and if you set the variable it will set the value of the dom element.

Comment: i am aware of that, but the value of ng-model for the input field is "xyz.zyx", which is set in the controller, and the variable name that i am accessing within the controller is "zzz". There are no elements on the page with ng-model="zzz". Where does "zzz" comes from is my question. How does the controller know what that value is, where does it take it from?

Comment: When your controller loads it is setting zyx to zzz but your input is binding to xyz.zyx which is changing the value of zyx through two way data-binding. To illustrate this further you can set $scope.zzz outside of your object to "Test" and your input will load with Test. However, when you type in your input zyx will change but your $scope.zzz will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put in a comment to your question but I also wanted to put together a plunker to help you tinker with what's going on.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vYI1XiSm4cnEJjLRSO85

js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MainCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.zzz = "Test";

  $scope.xyz = {
    zyx: $scope.zzz
  }
}
```

html

```
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angularjs_1_3_15@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="xyz.zyx">
    <pre>zzz: {{zzz | json}}</pre>
    <pre>xyz: {{xyz | json}}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```